# Cannot get PHP substr function to work

Tags: php, truncate

I want to truncate this code below which outputs a simple text line:

```
<?php echo $post->author->getTitle();?>
```

And so I did this:

```
<?php $post->author->getTitle();
   echo substr($post, 0, 15);
?>
```

However, I get this:

```
Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /entry/default.php on line 107
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
substr($post, 0, 15);
```

with:

```
substr($post->author->getTitle(),0,15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not caste the value of `$post->author->getTitle()`  to the variable `$post` thus you would have to do `$post = $post->author->getTitle()`  and and then `substr($post,0,15)`